New job, reporting manager is not replying to me after a few days: how to proceed?
I recently joined a new company and team. And the hiring manager assigned me my reporting manager a few days after I joined.  It has been a week and I've yet to be introduced to the team or have a conversation with my reporting manager regarding the exact project I will be working on.
The hiring manager seemed nice enough and asked good questions.  I was not interviewed by the reporting manager.
I have blocked off time on the reporting manager's calendar where he indicated he would reach out to me in a few minutes, but has yet to reach out or respond for that matter.
I have already emailed him to indicate I completed all of the mandatory training and will proceed to read up on the technology the team is using (ascertained at the time of the interview).
What are my options here?  I feel that reaching out to HR or employee relations could be a slippery slope just the same as not doing anything.

are you remote, or do you work in the same location as the manager and the rest of the team?

I am hybrid, no my manager is based out of another location, team members are also distributed, not close, but also not terribly far.  I contemplated showing up in person at his office, but that seems a bit excessive.

Has your manager replied to your email?

Are you working remotely, or in the same office?  If it's remote, then anything could be happening at the other end. I had a boss whose wife suddenly went into labour a whole month early, and he was just suddenly not online.  In that situation, some other team member, or the boss's boss should be able to inform you if something is amiss.

Is your manager even working at the moment? Are you sure they aren't on vacation and thus not reachable? Have you tried contacting the hiring manager as well?

out of curiosity - in which country do you live?


What are my options here?

Stop scheduling. Stop waiting. Call them directly. Now.
Via phone, via comunication software, whatever is available. Take initiative.
If you cannot reach them, try again in 5 minutes. Ask whoever you can reach. Not being in direct contact with your manager after a week is more than weird. I have never had a manager not contacting me on the very day I started.

I also don't want to come off as a pest.  Would it be out of line if I look at the org chart and reach out to whom I suspect my peers are?

@Walter Combining this with your comment on my answer, I would only do that if they are a direct report to your manager as well.  I agree with the other comments that say don't reach out to HR.  Reaching out to random people who don't work for your manager could have the same effect as reaching out to HR.  It could spiral out of control into something where it looks like the manager can't control his team.

It depends on your field and workplace and on your level. Where I work in software dev as a senior professional as long as I’m being granted access, am getting paid, and can reasonably find a way to fill (and charge) my time there’s no reason to pester a boss like this. Other situations may differ but unless you’re not getting a paycheck or can’t do anything without violating laws unless you talk to your boss, don’t do this. Pester your boss too much and you become the “problem employee” in their eyes.

Also note that large companies often do everything including onboarding slowly so that may be the case here (no idea what kind of company OP works in) and it’d be no reason to panic.

I don't see how "Hey boss, I haven't talked to you yet and it's been a full week" is "pestering". It is literally the managers job to talk to their team members. On the contrary, if I had a team member who cannot work productively and they don't do their utmost to tell me and just twiddled their thumbs for a week, I would wonder if I should let them go during probation. I feel bad when I tell new members to start at 9 and then a production emgergency comes up and I cannot meet them until eleven. A full week is ridiculous.

The absolute minimum a manager needs to do is delegate onboarding to a peer of the new hire.

@Walter also, I feel like contacting a peer (even a direct report of your same manager) would be more "pestering" than contacting your manager: it is your manager's job to manage your work, not your pees'. Do so only to try and reach your manager, and only if all else fails.

@Ngvoit Its not pestering to simply reach out. It is pestering to reach out every 5 minutes. That may not have been what you meant but it’s how it read to me.

@ngvoit Also note that work environments differ significantly. In some environments what you describe would be so weird as to warrant the level of urgency your describe in your answer, but there are many other work environments where the situation OP describes is unfortunately normal and reacting in perceived panic would put OP in a very bad light. So you might want to qualify your answer. It’s neither universally right nor universally wrong, it needs more context.

I don't know or have heard of any environment, where you would not meet your direct manager or a person they delegated to on your first day. If you are working in a field, country or company where this happens, feel free to share your experiences. I have no illusions about the fact that I don't know a lot of what is out there, but I cannot put "or maybe it is all different, who knows" behind every single of my answers.

I reached out to some former managers advising the same thing and then to follow-up with their manager if that fails.  I scheduled a meeting and just called him at the set time.  I got some information, not very much.  I also got a few other colleagues to follow-up with and get some information.  It seems like there is a bit of disorganization which is worrisome.  This is a new experience for me.  My experience with my managers in the past has been the opposite of this, while they're busy, they always have made time for me.

@Walter: Suggest putting that info as an update at the end of the question above. More visibility, might shape other answers, and sticky (whereas comments can be deleted at any time).

And keep a log of all your communication attempts.

@Walter, is the issue that you can't contact your manager, or is it merely that you aren't receiving proper direction and orientation, and arrangements aren't being made for your involvement in a normal way? It's obviously absurd not to be in contact. But with non-involvement, it's possible that your manager is just extremely busy and unprepared for your arrival, on top of which they may be inexperienced or not very competent.

I sympathize. When I was hired for my first tech job (many years ago and fully on-site), the day I arrived my team and manager didn't know I was coming, and there was no desk, no computer, no work available for me.
The no-work thing lasted for several weeks, and I remember this as being incredibly stressful (thinking I'd be let go, etc.). I was clearly being given disposable make-work tasks (like reorder header file listings) until they figured out something for me to do. It was about a month before I got legitimate work projects, but to this day it was probably the most stressful work period I've had.
I would recommend not tearing your hair out about this, sometimes that's just how corporate on-boarding works. If you're remote, maybe email your manager once a day about your availability. If you're getting paid, it should work itself out reasonably soon.

I had a consultant gig where it took two weeks to get a computer. Laughing all the way to the bank.

@nvoigt is correct in following up with them directly.  You may have to be more direct since you don't work in the same location.  With that said, it's not uncommon to have ramp up periods for tech jobs.
I previously worked in a development support role (on-site).  Essentially the company had a website with a database behind it.  I supported the website and the database.  However, my first 3 weeks consisted of them putting me in an isolated room and giving me access to the test database and basically saying "play around".  They did give me some "homework questions" that they did follow up on.  But overall, the first 3 weeks was very light and basically focused on getting me comfortable with the core database.
After that, my feet went to the fire pretty quickly.  I'd say enjoy the downtime and learn as much as you can about whatever tech they use.

Yeah, that is normal, I've been there before.  You had interfaced with your team and had clear direction on what to work on even if it was vague.

In addition to seeking out other contact options with your manager it might also be worthwhile to talk with several of your peers. Understanding the organization is part of any job and you'll see this add value in the sense that you are regarded as proactive. Essentially, this indirect approach will be nudging your manager without becoming a bother.
Recently we also had to bridge a very considerable time lag in our organization. After a mere 4 months (and several direct nudges before it would come across as stalking) I was finally contacted by an external organization whilst we had actually given up on the project. Repeated visibility with other clients appears to have driven this project forward. I must admit that we did not incur any cost during this time and 'neglecting' this specific contact allowed us to continue with items that we would usually spend our time on.

I agree that you should call them. I don't know how big the organisation is, what are the current circumstances (e.g. preparing for a new project, busy with existing customers, something personal in the manager's life, etc.), but do call the manager, then try the hiring manager and finally the HR.
I don't believe it's a slippery slope. Be genuine in your enquiries, after all you're there to help them and you need to know how to help them.
I've been in similar situations where very large corporations did not properly onboard me for months and afterwards failed to assign me any work - meanwhile I was still paid but unable to do anything. It can be frustrating. In one case I've solved it by reaching out to HR which put me in touch with another department that needed my expertise for a short while.

Yes it's the manager's job to contact you and assign you projects. You can call them or approach them personally if they are not on the phone or busy with someone else. Yes, managers can get this busy where it may be weeks until you talk to your direct manager.
In the mean time, make sure you get your computer, your login info, access to all network drives and other systems that you need. And get office supplies too. I think I have 30 usernames/passwords for work alone. Another 500 for home. Not all are used, but most are.
When I started one job I just designed a backup system using a cmd.exe batch file for my files that would be stored on my PC. We now have network drives that are backed up by the IT department and I store my work on there. Or I store files on our OneDrive which gets synced with the cloud.
I've been in similar situations. My direct manager replies to my emails normally within 48 hours but he too, does get busy. If I have a question about a project I'm assigned, this may be a low-priority project for him and he may not be able to answer it right away.
If I do jobs for other managers (who are not in my department) and I have a question for them that only they can answer, it may be 2-12 weeks before I hear back from them. They have many priorities and jobs seeking their time and my jobs just happened to be lower priority. If a job I'm working on gets close to a deadline then it becomes a higher priority for them and they return my emails more often.
I just follow up with them every 2 weeks. They seem fine with that.
In the meantime, find other departments physically nearby where you can help them. Ask for the supervisor and ask then if you can help them out. Be proactive.

While it is the manager's job to keep in touch with you and assign you work, you should take the initiative.
My approach would be to "Call him and make an appointment to discuss issues".  Discussing anything face to face is multiple times better than doing it over the phone, especially when you hardly know the other person.
At no stage should make this into a complaint to HR.  If you are unable to reach your manager than request the HR to make an appointment for you.  Then you can discuss your issues directly.
